# Solving and plotting roots of a transcendental equation against a log-spaced parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I  want to plot `K0` against `β`. In order to find the roots `Subscript[α, n]` of the transcendental equation, I need to substitute the parameter β that takes on values on the log scale.

```
β = 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100

eqn = Subscript[α, n]*
    BesselJ[1, Subscript[α, n]] == β*BesselJ[0, Subscript[α, n]];

roots = FindRoot[eqn, {Subscript[α, n], #}] & /@ Range[1]

K0 = roots^2
```

I am stuck here since I don't know how to remove the arrow in `K0` (which the arrow come from the solution of FindRoot). `K0` should be the square root of the root (differ for each value of `β` ).

I did the calculation for `K0` manually. I want to plot as listed below `K0` against `β` but I don't know how to ask Mathematica to list the answer in table and plot the graph.

```
 β = 0.01, α, n = 0.1412, K0 = (0.1412)^2 = 0.0199
 β = 0.1,  α, n = 0.4417, K0 = (0.4417)^2 = 0.1951
 β = 1,    α, n = 1.2558, K0 = (1.2558)^2 = 1.5770
 β = 10,   α, n = 2.1795, K0 = (2.1795)^2 = 4.7502
 β = 100,  α, n = 2.3809, K0 = (2.3809)^2 = 5.6687
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
β = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}
eqns = Subscript[α, n]*BesselJ[1, Subscript[α, n]] == #*
     BesselJ[0, Subscript[α, n]] & /@ β
roots = FindRoot[#, {Subscript[α, n], 1}] & /@ eqns
```

$$\left\{\left\{\alpha _n\to 0.141245\right\},\left\{\alpha _n\to 0.441682\right\},\left\{\alpha _n\to 1.25578\right\},\left\{\alpha _n\to 2.1795\right\},\left\{\alpha _n\to 2.3809\right\}\right\}$$

```
K0 = Subscript[α, n]^2 /. roots
```

> {0.0199501, 0.195083, 1.57699, 4.75021, 5.66869}

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{K0, β}]
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotStyle -> Red
 , MeshStyle -> Blue
 , Mesh -> All
 , ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}
 , AxesLabel -> {"K0", "β"}
 , Ticks -> {Range[1, 6, 1], PowerRange[0.01, 100]}
 , GridLines -> {Range[1, 6, 1], PowerRange[0.01, 100]}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT1-To flip axes**

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{β, K0}]
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotStyle -> Red
 , MeshStyle -> Blue
 , Mesh -> All
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}
 , AxesLabel -> {"β", "K0"}
 , Ticks -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
 , GridLines -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
 , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
 , PlotRange -> {{0.01, 110}, {-0.5, 6}}
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT2-To draw a smooth curve**

Using `InterpolationOrder`:

```
p1 = ListPlot[Transpose[{β, K0}]
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Black]
  , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}
  , AxesLabel -> {"β", "K0"}
  , Ticks -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
  , GridLines -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
  , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
  , PlotRange -> {{0.01, 110}, {-0.5, 6}}
  , InterpolationOrder -> 1
  , Epilog -> { Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], 
    Point@Transpose[{Log@β, K0}]
    }
  ];

p2 = ListPlot[Transpose[{β, K0}]
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Blue]
  , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}
  , AxesLabel -> {"β", "K0"}
  , Ticks -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
  , GridLines -> {PowerRange[0.01, 100], Range[1, 6, 1]}
  , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}, {Gray, Dotted}}
  , PlotRange -> {{0.01, 110}, {-0.5, 6}}
  , InterpolationOrder -> 2
  ];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However if I want the graph to be smooth curvy graph not like straight line as you did, is it possible ?

Comment: @Aifa, I have updated the answer. In this last case, I have not used `Mesh` for this  variation. You can choose to draw one or both curves. The code can be made more concise, but at the cost of readability, so I have chosen to plot `p1,p2` separately.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really help me to solve this :)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

It is recommend to use `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[
  a*BesselJ[1, a] == b*BesselJ[0, a], {b, 0, 100}, {a, 0, 6}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  FrameLabel -> {"β", "K0"}] /. {b_Real, a_Real} :> {b, a^2}
```

[image]

**Original**

Maybe like this.

```
Clear[α, b, β, sol, roots];
β = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100};
sol = α /. 
  Table[FindRoot[α*BesselJ[1, α] == 
     b*BesselJ[0, α], {α, 1}], {b, β}]
roots = sol^2;
ListPlot[Thread@{β, roots}, AxesLabel -> {"β", "K0"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However when I tried to replicate, it doesn't plot anything only the axis. I'm using Mathematica 12.0

Comment: @Aifa  a  typo, fixed now.

Comment: sorry for troubling again, can you help to change the axis K0 against \[Beta] and if I want the graph to be smooth curvy graph, if using ListPlot or ListLinePlot will not produce that graph isn't? I want a  smooth curvy graph that connected all the points. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Aifa Take cvgmt's first advice and try `ContourPlot[
  a*BesselJ[1, a] == b*BesselJ[0, a], {b, 0, 100}, {a, 0, 6}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Log[\[Beta]]", "K0"}] /. {b_Real, a_Real} :> {b, 
   a^2}`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann   Thanks, I don't note that the questionor have changed the title and change the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Format[αn] := Subscript[α, n]

eqn[β_] = αn*BesselJ[1, αn] == β*BesselJ[0, αn];

βValues = {0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5, 7.5, 10, 20, 50, 
   75, 100};

root[β_?NumericQ] := αn /. FindRoot[eqn[β], {αn, 1}]

Grid[
 Prepend[
  tab = {#, r = root[#], r^2} & /@ βValues,
  {β, αn, K0}],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[tab[[All, {1, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {β, K0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help :)